# How I can see files changes in git pull

Tags: git

I my PC when I run:

```
$ git pull
```

I can see this:

```
remote: Counting objects: 29, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (23/23), done.
remote: Total 29 (delta 13), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (29/29), done.
From bitbucket.org:myorg/myrepository
   ddad276..505c341  dev        -> origin/dev
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: New section
```

But in my server on the cloud I see something different when I run `git pull`:

```
remote: Counting objects: 29, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (23/23), done.
remote: Total 29 (delta 13), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (29/29), done.
From https://bitbucket.org/myorg/myrepository
   ddad276..505c341  dev        -> origin/dev
Updating ddad276..505c341
Fast-forward
 .../templates/myfile01.html.twig        |  8 ++++
 sites/css/custom.css  | 58 ++++++++++++++++++++-----
 .../sass/custom/_artifacts.scss  |  1 +
 .../sass/custom/_custom.scss     | 11 ++++-
.....................
```

Then, How I can config my local git to view those files that have changed ?

Comment: It seems your PC is configured to do `git pull --rebase`, while the server does a plain `pull` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn on verbose mode by run `pull -v`, and also it seems that you have `pull.rebase` == `true` in your git config